# Is Dell Vostro 3560 compatible with Full HD LCD?

Tags: motherboard, lcd, dell-inspiron

Recently I had a problem with Inspiron 5520 laptop, and I bought a new motherboard. By mistake, I bought mother board of Vostro 3560 which is almost identical.

I saw that there are websites that write in the specs that the lcd is 1920x1080. I have the lcd of inspiron 5520 1366x768.

So, how can I check wether my mobo support full hd lcd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Owner's User Manual](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_vostro_notebook/vostro-3560_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf) this motherboard supports resolution up to 1920x1080, so the answer is yes. But don't forget to check that also the lcd cable support it and the graphics card support it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter unless you upgrade the lcd, it will only do 1366x768.

There are to many configurations for video and the 3560 motherboard, some only had Intel HD 3000 or 4000 uma graphics, some had Nvidia GT630m or Radeon HD7670m, but like I said its the lcd that limits the resolution that can be displayed.

[3560 support page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/vostro-3560/manuals)